# How to wrapper Hibernate session API avoid of "unchecked" generics warning

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I'm coding a wrapper for Hibernate Session API:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> execQuery(String hql){
    Session s=sf.getCurrentSession();
    return s.createQuery(hql)
                .list();
}
```

The list() function of Hibernate Session API seems using raw type. so How can I wrapper this function, and let the client of my wrapper to safyly using like this:

```
  List<BusinessObject> bo= xxx.execQuery(...);
```

Comment: It looks like you already wrote it. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Can I avoid the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Comment: Why don't you use the standard JPA API, which doesn't use raw types as the ole Session API does?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to avoid having `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in at least one place.

Since `List` is a raw type you'll have to do an unchecked conversion *somewhere*. The best you can do is to keep it contained to one place, which is what you're doing with execQuery.